# startech USBA-BLUETOOTH-V5-C2 doesn't read headset pioneer SE MJ553BTR on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, bluetooth

i put my usb startech USBA-BLUETOOTH-V5-C2 in my pc with ubuntu 22.04, but usb doesn't read headset pioneer SE MJ553BTR on ubuntu 22.04. usb reads tv,smartphone and a speaker.

```
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2024-01-30 10:53:56 CET; 1h 23min ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 699 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 38347)
     Memory: 2.0M
        CPU: 84ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─699 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

gen 30 10:54:08 locra-AORUS-ELITE bluetoothd[699]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.38 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/faststream
gen 30 10:54:08 locra-AORUS-ELITE bluetoothd[699]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.38 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/faststream_duplex
gen 30 10:54:08 locra-AORUS-ELITE bluetoothd[699]: Failed to add UUID: Failed (0x03)
gen 30 12:14:53 locra-AORUS-ELITE bluetoothd[699]: Failed to add UUID: Failed (0x03)
gen 30 12:14:53 locra-AORUS-ELITE bluetoothd[699]: Failed to add UUID: Failed (0x03)
gen 30 12:14:53 locra-AORUS-ELITE bluetoothd[699]: Failed to add UUID: Failed (0x03)
gen 30 12:14:53 locra-AORUS-ELITE bluetoothd[699]: Failed to add UUID: Failed (0x03)
gen 30 12:14:53 locra-AORUS-ELITE bluetoothd[699]: Failed to add UUID: Failed (0x03)
gen 30 12:14:53 locra-AORUS-ELITE bluetoothd[699]: Failed to add UUID: Failed (0x03)
gen 30 12:14:53 locra-AORUS-ELITE bluetoothd[699]: Failed to add UUID: Failed (0x03)
```

this is lsusb output:   Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0bda:8771 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Bluetooth Radio1

```
sudo dmesg | grep -i blue
[sudo] password di locras: 
[    1.539640] usb 3-1: Product: Bluetooth Radio
[    4.186972] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    4.186997] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[    4.186999] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    4.187004] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    4.187007] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    4.187012] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    4.279792] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: examining hci_ver=0a hci_rev=000b lmp_ver=0a lmp_subver=8761
[    4.281666] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: rom_version status=0 version=1
[    4.281697] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8761bu_fw.bin
[    4.284536] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8761bu_config.bin
[    4.284925] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: cfg_sz 6, total sz 30210
[    4.556615] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: fw version 0xdfc6d922
[    5.028580] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    5.028587] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    5.028591] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    5.029622] Bluetooth: MGMT ver 1.22
[    5.250444] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[    5.250455] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[    5.250461] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
```

which is the problem?

Comment: @ArturMeinild did you know what i can add to understand the problem?

Comment: If you did something to your system, you should write this in detail, step by step. But sorry, I'm not an expert on Bluetooth.